# Javascript how to use reduce to get sum of an attribute's value from nested objects?

Tags: javascript, object, methods, nested, reduce

I have an object like the following:

```
data_sample = {
  "object_1": {
    "irrelevant_data1": 0,
    "irrelevant_data2": 0,
    "data_needed_to_sum_up": 100,
  },
  "object_a": {
    "irrelevant_data1": 0,
    "irrelevant_data2": 0,
    "irrelevant_data3": 0,
    "data_needed_to_sum_up": 200,
  },
  "object_d": {
    "irrelevant_data1": 0,
    "irrelevant_data2": 0,
    "data_needed_to_sum_up": 300,
  },
}
```

How can I use the `reduce` method to get the `sum` of all `data_needed_to_sum_up` inside `data_sample` to get the expected result of 600?

Comment: Thank you everyone. So what I have is just an object, thus `Object.values` is needed to get an array for `reduce` method to become usable and then achieve the desired result with `.reduce((acc,curr) => acc = acc + curr["data_needed_to_sum_up"],0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Object.values`to and then use `reduce`

```js
data_sample = { "object_1": { "irrelevant_data1": 0, "irrelevant_data2": 0, "data_needed_to_sum_up": 100, }, "object_a": { "irrelevant_data1": 0, "irrelevant_data2": 0, "irrelevant_data3": 0, "data_needed_to_sum_up": 200, }, "object_d": { "irrelevant_data1": 0, "irrelevant_data2": 0, "data_needed_to_sum_up": 300, }, }
res = Object.values(data_sample)
    .reduce((acc,curr) => acc = acc + curr["data_needed_to_sum_up"],0)
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.reduce` works on arrays, what you have is just an object, but you could use `.reduce` in conjunction with `Object.entries`, like so:

```js
data_sample = {
  "object_1": {
    "irrelevant_data1": 0,
    "irrelevant_data2": 0,
    "data_needed_to_sum_up": 100,
  },
  "object_a": {
    "irrelevant_data1": 0,
    "irrelevant_data2": 0,
    "irrelevant_data3": 0,
    "data_needed_to_sum_up": 200,
  },
  "object_d": {
    "irrelevant_data1": 0,
    "irrelevant_data2": 0,
    "data_needed_to_sum_up": 300,
  },
}

console.log(Object.entries(data_sample).reduce((carry, [_, current]) => carry + current.data_needed_to_sum_up, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```
let sum = Object.values(data_sample)
         .reduce((acc,cur)=>acc+cur.data_needed_to_sum_up,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
console.log(Object.values(data_sample).map((x) => x.data_needed_to_sum_up).reduce((x, y) => x + y));
```

Answer (score 0):

use Object.valuesto first then use reduce